# String to Date not formatted correctly

Tags: java, date

I am trying to do a simple String to Date conversion in Java. I am skimming the date off some logs and need to convert it to a date to do some processing. A date coming through will look like this:

```
2012-09-07 19:53:33
```

In my code when I try to convert this into a Date object I get a completely different date. My code looks like this:

```
String taskStart = "2012-09-07 19:53:33";  
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date taskStartDate = dateFormat.parse(taskStart);
```

The output I get is this:

```
Sat May 07 19:00:27 PDT 2016
```

How can I just simply convert my original date to the correct format??

Comment: I think there's a typo, did you mean to say `String format =...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You've specified `MM` (month in year) twice. The m's for "minute" must be lowercase.
2. If you're taking 24-hour based times, you need to specify `HH` in order to capture hours that are specified in the range of `0-23`, as opposed to `hh` which expects AM/PM hours (hours in the range of `1-12` with an AM/PM specifier as part of the time string)
3. Finally, your example code doesn't define the `format` variable that you're passing into the constructor for your `SimpleDateFormat` object. In fact, you're using the variable name `dateFormat` twice and not defining the `format` variable at all - at least not according to the code that you included in the question.

So, your proper format string, I believe, should be...

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

...and the full, proper code example would be:

```
String taskStart = "2012-09-07 19:53:33";  
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date taskStartDate = dateFormat.parse(taskStart);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you should use an upper case "H" for hours of the format 0-23. Also, minutes are represented by a lowercase "m".

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should convert again the date output to `String` format using date `formatter.format` function:

```
Date formatter=new SimpleDateFormatter("yy-MM-dd HH mm ss")

String s=formatter.format(taskStartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dateFormat definition to this:

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Note that the in your time, HH should be capitalized for 0-23 and mm should be lowercase for minute.

Answer (score 0):

`"yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss";`

`MM` and `mm` are for **Month and Minute respectively.....**

So it should be...

`"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";`